# gdbのattachについて

Tags: linux, gdb

os : Linux version 4.15.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3))

ユーザーの入力待受状態になっている自作プログラムに対して、違うpts番号を持つ別の仮想端末からgdbでアタッチしようとしているのですが失敗します。
プログラムはgcc -gオプション付きでコンパイルしました。
gdb -p (pid)でアタッチしようとしています。

以下がメッセージとしてgdb起動時に出力されます。
Attaching to process 16458
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: 許可されていない操作です.

質問の内容としましては、以上の状況で、
１．アタッチできない理由
２．どうすればアタッチできるようになるのか
が知りたいです。

ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: 参考までに、表示されているメッセージの一部で検索してみるとこんなページが見つかりました。 - https://pleiades.io/help/clion/attaching-to-local-process.html

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf に説明があります。

Answer (score 1):

コメントを参考にさせていただきながら、自己解決しました。

/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf の記述と
$ man 2 ptrace の記述を参照しました。

1.ubuntu環境では他のプログラムから制御を奪われることを避けるために、デフォルトではptace(2)でプロセスにアタッチすることができないように制約されている。
2.一時的にアタッチできるようにする(再起動でデフォルトの設定に戻る)
　　　　$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
　永続的にアタッチできるようにする
　　　　/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf の最終行
　　　　kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
　　　　の値を0に編集して保存。

以上でアタッチできるようになりました。